# I unable to view the packages in split view in Project Explorer in android studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 for android Development, recently i update Android Studio 2.3 from Stable Channel. There few bugs presently i got from IDE. Bugs are mentioned below: 
I created the new project, package and class files showing in project explorer is totally weird. Please see the images below that will clearly convey, what i'm trying to say.
how can i change the mode of package showing in explorer.

[image: android studio package did not showing in split mode]

I expected this kind of view in explorer, please see my images below
[image: Android Studio-2.2 package Explorer]

Comment: "I expected this kind of view in explorer" -- Add more classes and a package named `tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player`, and you'll get there. I see no issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to disable flat hierarchy in Project pane.

1. Click *Show Options menu* button.
2. Uncheck *Flatten Packages*.
3. Optional: Uncheck *Compact Empty Middle Packages*.

[image: Options menu]

Hierarchy with *Flatten Packages*:

- com.myapp.app

  - MyApplication.java
- com.myapp.ui

  - MyActivity.java

Hierarchy without *Flatten Packages*:

- com.myapp

  - app

    - MyApplication.java
  - ui

    - MyActivity.java

Comment: Hi Eugen,Thanks for the answer I saw this option, but this feature not available in android studio 2.3.
did u check with stable version of android studio?

Comment: @MohanRajS That gear icon is part of the entire IDE of IntelliJ IDEA, and therefore should exist in Android Studio, which is based on it.

Comment: @MohanRajS It's in Android Studio 2.3 Build #AI-162.3764568 on Windows and it's been in previous versions as well. What's in your options menu?

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio Dolphin and above.

```
setting icon -> tree appearance -> Compact Middle Packages (Uncheck this)
```

It will help you get package wise hierarchy.